# Specifying which parameters to be used when using arcpy.ImportToolbox function?

Tags: arcpy, parameters

This tool I have designed is to create a buffer around Gas or Power lines then append the newly buffered data into the planning area. My custom tool's script is as follows:

```
# Import System Modules
import arcpy
import os

#Set Workspace
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "C:/Code/Module7FProj"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Sets Parameters for Gas and Power line buffer for geoprocessing tool
GasPower_Lines_Buffer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Output_GasPower_Buffer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
GasPower_Buffer_Distance = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
Planning_Area = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
Append_GasPower_Lines = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)


# create a 25 foot buffer from power and gas lines
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(GasPower_Lines_Buffer, Output_GasPower_Buffer,     GasPower_Buffer_Distance)

# append buffered power and gas lines with planning file
arcpy.Append_management(Output_GasPower_Buffer, Planning_Area,     Append_GasPower_Lines)
```

I need to create a separate script which imports this tool, sets the multiple inputs for "GasPower_Lines_Buffer" and sets the input for "Planning_Area".

So far I have:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.ImportToolbox("C:/Code/Module7FProj/FinalProj.tbx")
# below is where I need to set the parameters from the 
# previous script. Alias of toolbox is "FinalProjToolbx"
arcpy.FinalProjToolbx.FinalProj
```

Comment: Cross-posted as http://stackoverflow.com/q/38686664/820534

Answer (score 1):

I find the best way to learn something like this is to make ArcGIS do it first.  You can do this by creating a model in ModelBuilder and adding your first script to it.  Export that simple model to script (Model > Export > To Python Script...) - you don't need to make the model do everything.

The new exported script will include the reference to your toolbox and first script.

My exported result:

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Load required toolboxes
arcpy.ImportToolbox("D:/temp/SE/tbtest/tb1.tbx")

# Process: My First Script
arcpy.myFirstScript_my_tb1()
```

The name of my script in the toolbox is `myFirstScript`, the name of my toolbox is `tb1.tbx` and the alias of my toolbox is `my_tb1`.  For referencing the tool in `arcpy` you combine the script name and the alias with an underscore `_`, which gives me `arcpy.myFirstScript_my_tb1()`.

This means your script would look something like this:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.ImportToolbox("C:/Code/Module7FProj/FinalProj.tbx")
# below is where I need to set the parameters from the 
# previous script. Alias of toolbox is "FinalProjToolbx"
arcpy.FinalProj_FinalProjToolbx()
```

Assuming `FinalProj` is the name of your first script, and `FinalProjToolbox` is the alias of your toolbox.